# When does the standard 404 page appear?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404

I am building a simple HTTP server for a project.
Most websites have custom 404 error pages. Sometimes though, you'll see Firefox spitting a generic 404 page (or 405, etc...).
How does it decide what to do?
What should the HTTP response be?
Is "HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND" enough?

Thanks

Comment: Surprisingly, even on April 2017 Firefox doesn't know how or when to show default error pages based on HTTP status codes. So far I haven't found a way to link an HTTP 500 error code to a default Firefox error page, while all other browsers understand that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Firefox won't show a generic 404 error page under most circumstances; you're thinking of Internet Explorer, which ignores a website's 404 page if it's below a certain size and displays its own.

Comment: what about other error numbers? Is the server supposed to send custom page for all, or can the browser handle that?

Comment: Chrome is also "broken"? Because it shows the correct, default 404 error page as well as Internal Sever Error and other default error pages properly. And Firefox is "right" because it just shows a blank page?.. Of course, it's better to show a blank page, and expect the user to open the developer toolbar, go to Network tab, reload the page, read the HTTP status code of the response, and Google that response to find out the meaning. Yes, that is a brilliant behaviour of the browser. Very user-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

If server can't find the requested resource (e.g. a webpage), it sends an **HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND** in the HTTP header section.

**Servers can map** an error page for this error, so you can get a readable error page. **Browsers can also map** an own error page, so you can see a browser-specific error 404 message.

You can see the error code in the **status field in log files**.

You can **redirect your user** to a specific page with this structure:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=not404.htm">
</head>
</HTML>
```

See details on [Welcome to 404 Error Pages .com](http://www.howtofriends.com/404error/)

Comment: The problem here is that only Chrome and IE are actually mapping HTTP status codes to actual default error pages. Firefox thinks that's it's easier for the user to show a totally blank page, and expects the user to open the developer toolbar, go to Network tab, reload the page, and read the HTTP status code of the response, then Google that response to find out the meaning. Yes, much easier than showing a default error page.. brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating an HTTP server you might want to look at the RFC that describes the protocol: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

For the 404 status code it says:

> The server has not found anything
>   matching the Request-URI. No
>   indication is given of whether the
>   condition is temporary or
>   permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code
>   SHOULD be used if the server    knows,
>   through some internally configurable
>   mechanism, that an old    resource is
>   permanently unavailable and has no
>   forwarding address.    This status
>   code is commonly used when the server
>   does not wish to    reveal exactly why
>   the request has been refused, or when
>   no other    response is applicable.

You can't control how the browser will treat each status code, you shuld rely on its good behaviour.

That said, you may benefit from using one of the existing HTTP servers. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/cc-web-server-library) on how to create an HTTP server in C or C++ posted few days ago,

Comment: You are correct. Chrome and IE behave properly and show the corresponding default error page, while Firefox thinks it's better to show a blank, empty page.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly valid to return an html body with a 404 response code. If no body is provided then the browser will show a default page.

1. If you only send **HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND** then the browser default will be displayed.
2. If you add a body to the response the browser will mostly use that.

Comment: To be picky, it's not the html body that contains the 404 response, it's the HTTP header ...

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4 - the server SHOULD include a body explaining the error.

Comment: The header contains the error code, the body contains the human-readable error message.

Comment: (*) Excepting Mozilla Firefox which shows an intuitive, user-friendly and totally BLANK page.

Answer (score -2):

Usually it set up in the webserver, ie: When the server gets a 404, refer it to this page.

Comment: As far as I know, the only browser that has a generic error page is MSIE.

Comment: @Quentin Chrome already shows response codes in a default error page.

Comment: @NathanH Believe it or not, 8 years later Firefox still refuses to show its default error pages.